# Kendo UI Grid DataSourceRequest and DataSourceRequestModelBinder in MVC6

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

There seems to be something going wrong when the `DataSourceRequestModelBinder` runs and tries to create a `DataSourceRequest` on the parameters sent in by the Grid.  This is in `MVC 6` with `Kendo.Mvc v2016.1.112`.

On the cshtml side, the Kendo DataSource looks like this:

```
var myDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    pageSize: 3,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/kendotest/GetKendoGridData"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total"
    }
});
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
[Route("GetKendoGridData")]
public DataSourceResult GetKendoGridData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    //create some sample objects
    var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
    var data = ids.Select(i => new MyModel
    {
        Id = i
    });

    return data.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

The initial read works fine, and paging works fine, but server side sorts do not.  I think this is because of the way the Kendo grid send in the sort parameters and results in the `DataSourceRequestModelBinder` not being able to parse it out.  I started to write my own ModelBinder but then decided to try to figure this out one more time.

It comes close when trying to supply sort parameters - the ModelBinder populates the Sort object, but the "Member" field is always null:
[image: No sort for you]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can happen if `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` is not included in your page.

Check [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction#manually-add-kendo-ui-to-aspnet-mvc-applications) is usefull.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been solved by adding `type: "webapi",` to my datasource.  So it would end up looking like this:

```
var myDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    pageSize: 3,
    type: "webapi",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/kendotest/GetKendoGridData"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total"
    }
});
```